# Contained by with default ID as a parameter doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I want to check if the id of a page of exercises is inside of an array for solvedExercises. I thought this might be easy to do with a contained_by, but it doesn't work.

I've tried this line (but I also want to randomise the questions)

```
randomQuestions = Exercises.objects.filter(id__contained_by=(req.user.profile.exercitiiProvocari).order_by("?")
```

but it doesn't work.
I'm getting this error:

```
Unsupported lookup 'contained_by' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted, perhaps you meant contains or icontains?
```

I suppose this error comes from the fact that ID is an auto-generated field by django, but I have no idea how to fix it.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from exercitii.models import Exercises 

# Create your views here.
def index(req):
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/provocari.html")

def provocari(req):
    randomQuestions = Exercises.objects.filter(id__contained_by=(req.user.profile.exercitiiProvocari).order_by("?")
    print(randomQuestions)
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/provocare.html")
```

Exercitii model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from lectii.models import Lectie

# Create your models here.
class Exercises(models.Model):
    idLectie = models.ForeignKey(Lectie, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    intrebare = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    variante = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=300), null=True)
    variantaCorecta = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.intrebare
```

So what I'm actually doing is to try to make the difference of an array of all exercises with one with the IDs of already solved exercises, and randomising the result.

But when I'm trying to make this difference, I get that error.

Comment: It seems like the parethesis  in the query are not equilibrated; there seems to be one more opening parethesis than closing parethesis. Could you double-check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple [`in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) be sufficient for this case?

Assuming `req.user.profile.exercitiiProvocari` is some kind of array/list/container, you could try something like this:

```
randomQuestions = Exercises.objects.filter(id__in=req.user.profile.exercitiiProvocari)\
    .order_by("?")
```

---

To exclude the seem questions, you could try using [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#exclude). This will return all questions that are NOT in `req.user.profile.exercitiiProvocari` and they should be in a random order:

```
randomQuestions = Exercises.objects.exclude(id__in=req.user.profile.exercitiiProvocari)\
    .order_by("?")
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want the ID to be. I tried to make it work like this atm, but after that I would want to try a negation operator. So "in" can't work I think.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu have you tried [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) instead of `filter()` ?

Comment: I didn't even know it existed tbh. I've searched the docs only for a negation operator to use in filter. Can you show me how this would be?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu just replace `filter()` for `exclude()`; see my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot :)